# Oculus Quest 2 Android Studio 'android.debug.keystore' not found error

Tags: android, android-studio, oculusquest

I'm going through the documentations Oculus Quest 2 [Native-MobileSDK-Getting Started-Android Studio Basics](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-studio-basics/), and I'm stuck with the following Android Studio error:

```
Execution failed for task ':VrSamples:VrCubeWorld_Framework:Projects:Android:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\thisUser\Downloads\OculusMobileSDK\VrSamples\VrCubeWorld_Framework\Projects\Android\android.debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'.
```

The tutorial says nothing about how to get this "android.debug.keystore" file.

I've read the [Quest 2 Android Application Signing page](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-application-signing/), but these steps create a .jks file not a .keystore file. I tried renaming the ".jks" file to "android.debug.keystore" and placing it in the correct directory, but I get a "failed to decrypt" error.

I've asked for help on Oculus support page and Oculus forums, but no one has been of help.

Can someone please help me with this issue? I am new to Android developement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the code to run. Here's what I did:

- Install Jave SE Development Kit 17.0.1.
- Open Command Prompt and enter the following:

  *cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin*

  *keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore android.debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000*
- The file *android.debug.keystore* will be created in the directory *cd
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin*. Move *android.debug.keystore*
  file to the appropriate directory. For me, it was
  *C:\Users\thisUser\Downloads\OculusMobileSDK\VrSamples\VrCubeWorld_Framework\Projects\Android*
- In Android Studio, go to
  *File-Settings-Build,Execution,Deployment-Build Tools-Gradle*. In
  Gradle settings, change Gradle JDK to version 15. For me, I had to
  download and use corretto-15 Amazon version.